# Password protect xml for WebClient download

Tags: asp.net, webclient, networkcredentials

I want to username/password protect xml file (www.domain.com/dir1/file.xml)
There could also be www.domain.com/dir2/file.xml with different credentials etc.

I am using asp.net 4.0 c#.

It has to be available for download using WebClient, something like.

```
public static string DownloadString(string address) 
{
    string text;
    using (var client = new WebClient()) 
    {
        text = client.DownloadString(address);
    }
    return text;
}
```

Do I set credentials on directory and combine it authorization in web.config or there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Why not encrypt your xml and decrypt them on the client side?

Comment: @thierry not an option